# How can I embed a plotly vizualization to a google slides?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, plotly, embed, google-slides

I have a plotly visualization in a Jupyter Notebook.
Looking for some time how to embed that file to google slides but couldn't find a way.
Does anyone know how I can visualize a plotly plot on the google slides without losing its interactivity?

thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 3):

### That's not possible if you want to keep the interactivity

Google Slides doesn't support [external iframes](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/90569#zippy=%2Cadd-html-css-or-javascript-code-to-your-site) or HTML code. As an almost workaround you can export the plot [as an image](https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/), it's still non-interactive though.